# Android tabview icon not show

Tags: android-tabs

[image]

Tabbar icon not showing

I try change `res.getDrawble(R.drawble.ic_alarm)` but not showed.

I use `Fragment/ViewPager` so make `FakeContent`

```
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
Resources res = getResources();

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab1", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.alarm));
tabSpec.setContent(new FakeContent(getApplicationContext()));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2");
tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alarm));
tabSpec.setContent(new FakeContent(getApplicationContext()));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3");
tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab3",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alarm));
tabSpec.setContent(new FakeContent(getApplicationContext()));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
```

XML `ic_alarm`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/alarm" android:state_selected="true" />
     </selector>
```

Comment: Do you mean icon shows up for Tab1, but not for Tab 2 and 3 ?

Comment: My point is Tab 1 you call "R.drawable.alarm" and for Tab 2 and 3 you call "R.drawable.ic_alarm".
Could you please give more details about your issue

Comment: i add a image. I want tabbar "tab1+ alarm icon " +"tab2+ alarm icon " +"tab3+ alarm icon "  , just 'tabname' showing